# How to Use GXT Button.setIcon / AbstractImagePrototype

Tags: gxt

I am trying to extends the AbstractImagePrototype as below:

public class DynamicImagePrototype extends AbstractImagePrototype {
    private String imagePath = null;

```
public DynamicImagePrototype (String imagePath) {
    this.imagePath = imagePath;
}

@Override
public void applyTo(Image image) 
{

}

@Override
public Image createImage() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Image image = new Image(imagePath);

    return image;
}

@Override
public String getHTML() {
    return null;
}
```

}

I used it as below:

item = new Button()
DynamicImagePrototype image = new DynamicImagePrototype("C:/temp/icons/reporting.gif");
item.setIcon(image);

However, it throw an exception.

My goal is that given an image file name, I want to return an AbstractImagePrototype so I can pass to Button.setIcon();

Thank you greatly for help!

Comment: If its just to set an icon on a button use the `IconHelper.create()` no need to implement your own version.. is there any other requirement thats missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, I have not found an answer for getting the AbstractImagePrototype dynamically yet.  I have to use static deferred binding as below:

```
public interface ReefDesktopIconsShortcuts
extends ImageBundle
{
   AbstractImagePrototype anImage();
}
```

In the directory where this interface resides, I have an image named "anImage.gif".

Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

Your class should be like this:

```
public interface ReefDesktopIconShortcuts extends ClientBundle {

public static final ReefDesktopIconShortcuts INSTANCE = (ReefDesktopIconShortcuts) GWT.create(ReefDesktopIconShortcuts.class);

public ImageResource anImage();
}
```

Just call this line:

```
yourBtn.setIcon(AbstractImagePrototype.create(ReefDesktopIconShortcuts.INSTANCE.anImage()));
```